# Best way to JOIN MySQL and MongoDB data

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, aggregation-framework

I have an application made ​​in PHP with Symfony, MariaDB and MongoDB.

The requirements of the application need to have a hierarchy (relationships) where MariaDB is who takes responsibility and each record is different is more a document a record, MongoDB is used to solve it. MongoDB Aggregation Framework it's used for statistical reporting through a dynamic custom made generator.

The problem arises when you need to cross information (JOIN) in MongoDB

Sample:

```
; Sample model
A -- 1:M -- B
B -- 1:M -- C
C -- M:M -- D
A -- 1:M -- E
```

Each entity has at least 2 columns

- `id`: AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
- `slug`: Mongo ObjectID

now a random entity A(id = 24) has the following data (documents) on mongodb

```
{
  name: "Motoko Kusanagi",
  powers: ["Superhuman strength", "genius-level intellect", "first-class hacker"]
}
```

and has 2 D entities (through C --> B --> A(id = 24)) with the following data

```
// D(id = 35)
{
  date: "2005-10-30 T 10:45 UTC",
  kills: 2
}

// D(id = 1235)
{
  date: "2007-11-09 T 11:20 UTC",
  tachikoma: 2,
  kills: 5
}
```

Sample reports:

- I want to know how many kills have the major Kusanagi
- I want to know when was the day that had more kills
- I want to know how many deaths occurred in a period X (after 2005 or before 2006-04-10), grouped by time (days or months or years)

the current development can solve the previous questions but only when the data exist in one document. how i can join the data, or how i can build a index for search all this things together

Comment: Suggestion: try to migrate one db to another and do the query on one.

Comment: that's what I'm evaluating a couple of days ago. I'm trying to avoid refactoring. with MySQL we lost the ability to have diferent structure records (a requirement) and with Mongo is dificult cross collection queries